# GridLines using SciDraw

Tags: graphics, scidraw

Does anyone knows how to include GridLines in Scidraw?

I have looked up in the whole documentation and there is nothing related to it.

Comment: As a last resort, you can generate them manually (`Table` and `Line`).

Comment: `GridLines->Automatic`  works for me.  It's standard Mathematica, not something that is peculiar to SciDraw.