# GridLines missing using SciDraw

Tags: grid-lines, scidraw

Does anybody know how to include standard GridLines in SciDraw? I found [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195365/gridlines-using-scidraw) but it doesn´t really answer the question. Here my minimal example reproducing the problem:

```
Figure[
  FigurePanel[
    {FigGraphics[
      Plot[{x, x - 2, x + 2, 2 - x}, {x, 0, 4}, 
      GridLines -> Automatic]
    ]}, XPlotRange -> {0, 4}, YPlotRange -> {0, 4}],
  CanvasSize -> {5, 3.5}*1.3
]
```

[image: output using SciDraw]

There are no GridLines in my output. However, simiply using the following
`Plot[{x, x - 2, x + 2, 2 - x}, {x, 0, 4}, GridLines -> Automatic]`
results in normal expected gridlines in the plot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like something specific to SciDraw itself rather than Mathematica.  Perhaps something in `Figure`, `FigurePanel`, or `FigGraphics` overrides the `Plot`'s `Gridlines` specification analogous to how such a specification in the first of 2 plots in a `Show` will override such formatting in subsequent plots.  Unless you get an answer from a knowledgable/experienced SciDraw user, probably best to reach out to [Mark A. Caprio](https://scidraw.nd.edu) at University of Notre Dame directly.

Comment: Any particular reason to use the package? It has not been updated since 2016 & now such things as `PlotGrid`, a resource function, and the proper usage/knowledge of `Charting\`ScaledTicks` makes the package not so warranted as before.

Comment: I know that it hasn´t been updated in a while, I just really liked the look and thought it would be a good resource for nice "paper-worthy" plots that fit nicely into my LaTeX-written thesis. Do you have any recommendations on other packages that would make good-looking graphs that mesh well with LaTeX? I have heard a lot about MaTeX for example.